# Etwaige vs. Irgendwelche

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Gibt's da überhaupt einen Unterschied? Ist es nur einfach so, dass "etwaige" die formale Form von "irgendwelche" ist?

Comment: [tag:grammar]???

Comment: Nebenbei: Was sagen die Wörterbucheinträge?

Comment: Es wäre anzumerken, dass *etwaig* sich im normalen Sprachgebrauch durchaus "überformal" anhört (also "geschraubt"). Weitere Anmerkung: Die Schweizer benutzen ein schönes Ersatzwort dafür: "allfällig" (möglicherweise auch A?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bei *etwaig* ist nicht klar, ob das nachstehende Substantiv einen eintretenden Umstand bezeichnet, im Beispiel *etwaiger Kosten* können auch durchaus **keine** Kosten entstehen.

Bei *irgendwelche Kosten* ist schon klar, **dass** Kosten entstehen, aber nicht

- durch wen
- in welcher Höhe.

Die beiden Wörter unterscheiden sich also deutlich im Grad der Ungewissheit.

Answer (score 3):

Mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass es durchaus einen Unterschied gibt. Am Beispiel der folgenden Sätze kann man das vernünftig herausarbeiten:

> Ich sehe irgendwelche Kinder auf dem Spielplatz spielen.

Es sind also gerade tatsächlich Kinder auf dem Spielplatz, die ich spielen sehe, von denen ich aber schlicht die Namen nicht kenne. Es geht also um etwas, das `faktisch` da ist, nur nicht näher benannt werden kann oder soll.

> Etwaige auftretende Kosten werden von den beiden Parteien zu gleichen Teilen übernommen.

Es ist überhaupt nicht klar, ob Kosten auftreten werden. Sollten Sie das aber, so werden sie geteilt. Hier ist klar, dass `Unsicherheit` mit in die Formulierung mit hineinspielt.

Ein Blick in den [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/etwaig) bestätigt meines Erachtens die Vermutung, dass ein Synonym für `etwaig` viel eher `eventuell` als `irgendwelche` wäre.

In der Umgangssprache gebe ich Ihnen aber sofort Recht, dass beides fröhlich gemischt wird und ein semantischer Unterschied kaum gegeben ist bzw. herausgearbeitet wird.